# The review privilege isn't mentioned on the edit privilege description page

Tags: support, review, privileges-page

[I just learned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work/76284#76284) that the review privilege is attached to the [*Edit questions and answers* privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) (rep >= 2000):

> All users with the Edit privilege may vote on suggested edits to posts.

This privilege is not mentioned on the edit privilege description page. It can be added as follows (copied from the [*Approve tag wiki edits* privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) description page):

> **Finding proposed edits to vote on**
>
> Users with the privilege to edit also have access to the suggested edit tab in the [review section](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Comment: I could have been helpful long before I was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The review privilege is available to anyone. You get access to the suggested edits queue at 5000 rep. Till then you can only vote upon suggested edits that you run into when visiting the question.

Comment: Aah, ok! Then the [_Approve tag wiki edits_ privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) description page needs an edit stating this.

Comment: @NGLN updated the tag wiki, it should get reflected soon.

Comment: Nice. It's difficult to try out functionality for lower reputation. Thanks for clearing this out.